# How to use pos_hint with FloatLayout in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to align labels and button in my test UI this is my kv file

```
<test>:   

    Label:        
        text: "foo"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        #pos:120,20
        pos_hint:{"right":0.1,"top":1}
    Label:
        text:"boo"
        color: 0,0,1,1
        #pos:80,20
        pos_hint:{"right":0.1,"top":0.5}

    Label:
        text:"bar"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        #pos:20,120
        pos_hint:{"right":0.1,"top":0.1}
    Button:
        text:"goo"
        size_hint:0.1,0.1
```

I am able to succesfully create labels foo,boo and bar using *pos* but when I used *pos_hint* it returns blank output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting "blank" output because the text of the labels is off screen (and the labels themselves are transparent).

1. Since your layout `<test>` has no `size_hint` so it takes on the
   default of `(1,1)` which makes it the size of the `Window` (which is
   `800 x 600`).
2. Your labels also don't have a `size_hint` so they default to the `size` of their parent - the layout, so they end up having `size [800, 600]`. The text in the labels is centered by default, and their background is transparent. (maybe you should try this with buttons first so you have a visual representation of the sizes)
3. Thus, the **text** a label with `pos = (0,0)` will appear in the center of the screen

Then we have the `pos_hint` taking different arguments (the below description might not be accurate for things outside of a `FloatLayout`):

`pos_hint:{"right":v1,"top":v2}` sets the `pos` to `(self.parent.right*v1 - self.width, self.parent.top*v2 - self.height)` - you are setting the `top` and `right` of the widget you are placing. Thus your labels get such negative coordinates that their texts never appear on screen (because bottom left is `0,0`)

then we have `pos_hint:{"x":v1,"y":v2}` (which you may find more useful for your case), and `pos_hint:{"center_x":v1,"center_y":v2}`. You should be able to figure out how they work bearing in mind that the size affects how things looks, since `pos` only sets the bottom left coordinate.. you can play around with this .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<test>:   
    #size: (500, 500)
    #size_hint:(None, None)
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Rectangle:
            size: (5,5)
            pos: (0,0)

    Widget:
        id:wig
        pos: (250,250)
        canvas:
            Color: 
                rgb: 1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: (5,5)
                pos: self.pos

    Label:
        id: boo
        text:"boo"
        color: 0,0,1,1
        #size_hint:(1,1)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":1,"center_y":1}

    Label:
        id: foo
        text: "foo"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        #size_hint: (.6,.6)
        pos_hint:{"x":1,"y":1}

    Label:
        id: bar
        text:"bar"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        #size:(500,500)
        #size_hint:(None, None)
        pos_hint:{"right":1,"top":1}
        #pos:100, 10


    Button:
        text:"goo"
        size_hint:0.1,0.1
        pos:(1,1)
        #some debug info, i know the code is ugly
        on_press: print self.parent.size,'\n', self.parent.right, self.parent.top, self.parent.x, self.parent.y, self.parent.center_x, self.parent.center_y, "\n","bar_right_top:", bar.pos,"foo_x_y:", foo.pos,"boo_center:", boo.pos, "\nwhite square:", wig.pos, "\n", bar.size, foo.size, boo.size
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `pos_hint:{'right': 1 - self.width, 'top': 0.5 - (self.height / 2)`? I have no problem to use calculations like `'top': 0.4 + 0.1}` but with self.height or width the button always disappears.

Comment: @Alex_P The button is off-screen. All of the `pos_hint`s expect values between 0 and 1, and your calculations leave that area as soon as you have a widget size larger than 1x1.

Comment: The suggestion to `try this with buttons first so you have a visual representation of the sizes` really helped me out today. +1